# Solving KNKING exercise 14, chapter 8. Reverse the words

Tags: c

I'm reading K.N.King C programming and I have an issue about it.

I'm solving project 5, chapter 12 which is modify project 14 from chapter 8 by using the pointer .

> Project 8.14
>
> Write a program that reverses the words in a sentence:

> Enter a sentence: you can cage a swallow can't you?
>
> Reversal of sentence: you can't swallow a cage can you?

> Hint: Use a loop to read
> the characters one by one and store them in a one-dimensional char
> array. Have the loop stop at a period, question mark, or exclamation
> point (the "terminating character"), which is saved in a separate char
> variable. Then use a second loop to search backward through the array
> for the beginning of the last word. Print the last word, then search
> backward for the next-to-last word. Repeat until the beginning of the
> array is reached. Finally, print the terminating character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 100


int main()
{
    char arr[N] = {0};
    
    char *p, *q, mark = 0;
    int c;
    p = arr;
    
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && p < arr + N)
    {
        
        if(c == '?' || c == '.' || c == '!')
        {
            mark = c;
            break;
        }
        else
            *p++ = c;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    
    while(p >= arr)
    {
        while(*--p != ' ' && p != arr);
        q = p == arr ? arr : p + 1;
        
        while(*q != '\0' && *q != ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", *q++);
        }
        if(p >= arr)
            printf(" ");
        
    }
    printf("\b%c", mark);
    printf("\n");
}
```

the problem is if I enter enter a sentence "My name is jiyong!", expected output is "jiyong is name My!" but the output always has '\xxx'. How can I get rid off? and what is these '\xxx' things?

ran under Xcode 12.4

Comment: You're outputting a backspace (`\b`) before the final punctuation mark. Why?

Comment: because there will be a additional space "jiyong is name My !"

Comment: I suggest you run this program through a debugger to find out what the problem is. However, I can't see any good reason for using a backspace to remove a character that shouldn't have been output in the first place. Perhaps changing `p >= arr` to `p > arr` would make more sense?

Comment: OK. thanks for helping me! I'll work on it!

Comment: A minor omission: you properly considered a possible overflow and added a condition (`p < arr + N`) to prevent it, but you did not consider the implications of such incidence. It turns out the `mark` variable remains `0` in such case, which causes you to `printf` a NUL character before the newline. This is probably not a desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop looks too complicated to me. You are required to scan the string backwards and print every word found, right? But you're *not* required to retain the whole sentence...?

So we can replace every space character with zero, thus terminating each word.

```
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && p < arr + N)
    {
    
        if(c == '?' || c == '.' || c == '!')
        {
            mark = c;
            break;
        }
        else
            *p++ = (c == ' ') ? '\0' : c;
    }
    *p = '\0';
```

Then we can seek words backwards and print them as strings instead of iterating over their characters:

```
    while(--p > arr)    // all words except the first one
    {
        if(!*p && p[1]) //p[1] or *(p + 1)
            printf("%s ", p+1);
    }

    printf("%s", arr);  // the first word goes last
    if(mark)
        printf("%c", mark);

    printf("\n");
```

I assumed `p` gets incremented at least once in the first loop, that is the input line is never empty. But that seems a valid assumption (although not very safe) as the input is defined as 'a sentence', so it *should not* be empty...

Comment: @Sanchez Thank you for fixing my mistake!

Comment: I just learned that pointer thing hh. I was so happy that I could fix something XD Thank you for the solution. surprised how tidy the code is!